# Gradle not generate jar

Tags: java, gradle, jar, compilation

I have a problem with gradle. 
My project It consists of several modules (osgi). 
When I run command:
./gradlew clean assemble
Gradle generate the jar file for each module, but I want use the command:
./gradlew clean compileJava
to speed up the work, but with this command gradle don't generate the jar file for two module. 
what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the diagram in *figure 1* from  [this documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#lifecycle_tasks) the dependencies between Java plugin tasks:

- see that `assemble` tasks dependes on `jar` task: this is why when you execute `gradlew assemble` Gradle will build the jar for each module
- see that `compileJava` task has no dependency: this task will simply compile your java source file into `.class` files. That's why no jar will be produced if you execute only `gradlew clean compileJava`.

What is strange is that you say you get the jar procuded when invoking `gradle compileJave` :  Gradle should normally not produce these jars.